# Visit domain model with second thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

My domain model is large tree structure that is modified by application. I would like to implement search in BackgroundWorker (separate thread to not block the UI).

Currently tree structure is implemented with ObservableCollection, that cannot be enumerated while it is modified, so my search will fail if user modifies tree while I am searching through it.

What is elegant solution for this problem? My requirements: do not block user from doing anything (operation should be async), search on separate thread (to speed things up).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I can think of that you can achieve what you need:

1. When writing, use `lock`, create a copy of the collection, add to the copy and then re-assign the collection to the copy.

Here is some code so you can test the above method. Create a form with a `ListBox` and a `Button`. While the list is being searched on a thread, you can add items to the list using the button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsForms {
   public partial class Form1 : Form {

      object key = new object();
      private List<string> items;
      public Form1() {

         InitializeComponent();
         items = new List<string>();
         for( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
            this.items.Add( i.ToString() );
         }
         this.listBox1.DataSource = this.items;
      }

      private void Read() {

         foreach( var thisItem in this.items ) {
            if (thisItem.ToString() == "100000" ) {
               MessageBox.Show( "Found" );
            }
            else {
               Thread.Sleep( 100 );
            }
         }
      }

      private void buttonStation2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         lock( this.key ) {
            var copy = new List<string>( this.items );
            copy.Add( "1000001" );
            this.items = copy;
         }
      }

      private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         Thread reader = new Thread( Read );
         reader.Start();
      }
   }
}
```

You may also want to make the collection variable `volatile` so a cached version is not used and you always get the latest when reading. However, you really need to know what the [volatile](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/threading-understanding-the-volatile-modifier-in-csharp/) keyword does before using it so that is why I did not use it in my code and left it up to you to decide. Also, other SO users may chime in and offer their advice using `volatile` in the comments to this answer if they wish.

```
private volatile List<string> items;
```